# Make a grading Calculator with Functions?

Tags: python, function, calculator, variable-assignment

I am doing a school assignment, and can not figure out despite how much I have tried, how to make the raw input change except to make each one individually,
Below is my assignment parameters:

[image]

- Prompt the user to enter in a numerical score for a Math Class. The numerical score should be between 0 and 100.
- Prompt the user to enter in a numerical score for a English Class. The numerical score should be between 0 and 100.
- Prompt the user to enter in a numerical score for a PE Class. The numerical score should be between 0 and 100.
- Prompt the user to enter in a numerical score for a Science Class. The numerical score should be between 0 and 100.
- Prompt the user to enter in a numerical score for an Art Class. The numerical score should be between 0 and 100.
- Call the letter grade function 5 times (once for each class).
  Output the numerical score and the letter grade for each class.

And this is what I have done:

```py
class_list=(['Math','Science','English','P.E.','Art'])

for i in class_list:
    grades = int(input('What is your score for math: ',class_list[1])),
  
def score (grade):
  if grade>=93: 
     return ("A")
  elif grade >=90 and grade<=93:
     return ("-A")
  elif grade >= 87 and grade<=90:
      return("B+")
  elif grade>=83 and grade >=87:
     return ("B")
  elif grade >= 80 and grade >=83:
     return ("B-")
  elif grade >= 77 and grade >80:
    return ("C+")
  elif grade >= 73 and grade >= 77:
       return ("C")
  elif grade >= 70 and grade >=73:
     return ("C-")
  elif grade>= 67 and grade >= 70:
   return  ("D+")
  elif grade >=63 and grade >=67:
   return ("D")
  elif grade >=60 and grade >=63:
    return ("D-")
  else:
     return ("F")
     
print  ("For an average score of"),grade, ("your grade is %s") % (score (grade))
```

Any advice?

Comment: How do you want to change the raw_input?

Comment: I want to be able to make it say different subjects from the list instead of just asking for the score, it should output "what is the score for math:" then "what is the score for science"... etc.

Comment: The below code will do it; simply copy paste into your interactive python shell :) (Consider Searching For "f-strings" in Python)

Answer (score 0):

For Python 3.2+ (iirc)

```
# convert the things to Py 2.x :); The below is one of the way;

class_list=['Math','Science','English','P.E.','Art']
my_dict = {}

for (idx,subject) in enumerate(class_list):
    my_dict[subject] = int(input(f"What is your score for {class_list[idx]} :")) # my_dict.update({subject : int(input(f"What is your score for {class_list[idx]} : "))})

# Calculate letter grade of each student 
def assign_letter_grade(grade):
    if grade >= 93: 
        return ("A")
    elif grade >= 90 and grade <= 93:
        return ("A-")
    elif grade >= 87 and grade <= 90:
        return("B+")
    elif grade>=83 and grade >= 87:
        return ("B")
    elif grade >= 80 and grade >= 83:
        return ("B-")
    elif grade >= 77 and grade > 80:
        return ("C+")
    elif grade >= 73 and grade >= 77:
        return ("C")
    elif grade >= 70 and grade >=73:
        return ("C-")
    elif grade>= 67 and grade >= 70:
        return  ("D+")
    elif grade >= 63 and grade >= 67:
        return ("D")
    elif grade >= 60 and grade >= 63:
        return ("D-")
    else:
        return ("F")

for subject in my_dict:
    print(f"For {subject}, a score of {my_dict[subject]}, you are eligible to get grade as {assign_letter_grade(my_dict[subject])}")
```

For Python 2.x

```
class_list=['Math','Science','English','P.E.','Art']
my_dict = {}
for idx,subject in enumerate(class_list):
    print("What is your score for :", class_list[idx])
    my_dict[subject] = int(raw_input())
print(my_dict)
```

Comment: is this python 2.7? It wouldn't run when I tried it?

Comment: Py 2.x is dead, Try moving to 3.6+ now :)

Comment: haha I have to learn it for school. Thanks so Much!! Its's been driving me crazy. I started this assignment Monday.

Comment: It's a very easy assignment :); I can post the end to end solution if you want; let me know :)

Comment: Do you know how to make each function print the results you input? like for example if I input 90 for math in the raw input, then wanted it to print "for math a score of 90, you got an A"

Comment: That would be great THanks for the help.

Comment: @Katherinemagistri Added a sample for Py3.x+; Convert it to Py 2.x :); Also NB Home-works aren't encouraged here :)